# How do I kill the lockscreen after the Windows 10 anniversary update?

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, windows-10-v1607

The Windows 10 "anniversary update" is coming out tomorrow and according to some [reports](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/07/28/microsoft-removes-policies-windows-10-pro/) the group policy to disable the lock screen is no longer effective on anything below the Enterprise edition. I'd like to know what options/workarounds are left to disable this nonsense on Pro editions.

Regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**For Anniversary Update Builds**

There is a workaround to disable the Lock Screen in Anniversary Update builds, in any edition of Windows.

Create a Scheduled Task that runs the following command-line, or a batch/script that runs the following command:

```
reg.exe add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData /t REG_DWORD /v AllowLockScreen /d 0 /f
```

The idea is to reset the `AllowLockScreen` value data to 0 on these two trigger events:

- Log on
- Workstation unlock.

So you need to use multiple triggers for that task.

(or)

Download the Task XML from here:
[How to Disable the Lock Screen in Windows 10 Anniversary Update (1607)?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-lock-screen-anniversary-update-windows-10/)

And use the Import Task option in Scheduler to create/import the task automatically.

Lock the workstation and unlock it. From the 2nd time onwards you shouldn't see the lock screen.

**For Pre-Anniversary Update Builds**

Start `Regedit.exe` and go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
```

Create a subkey named `Personalization`

Select `Personalization` and in the right-pane, create a REG_DWORD value named `NoLockScreen` and set its value data to `1`.

Exit the Registry Editor.

This registry edit corresponds to the following GPO.

> Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel >
>   Personalization > Do not display the lock screen

Comment: I can confirm this does work, if you're creating the task manually make sure to make it run as the "SYSTEM" user instead of your own account.

Comment: This works when I manually lock the computer, but on every boot the lock screen still shows.

Comment: Don't use this scheduled task! It's dangerous! I installed it and then my computer was almost broken. It could no longer log off or shut down. After restart, Explorer was constantly crashing until the system locked completely. I needed to delete this task with regedit in safe mode, now it works again.

Comment: I agree with @oKtosiTe in that it only seems to affect the lock screen when locking / unlocking, not on boot. I can't imagine why Microsoft thinks the lock screen is a good idea.

Comment: The boot “lock” screen is different. It isn’t associated with a session. That’s also why Spotlight (the image changer thingy) doesn’t work there.

Comment: I agree with @oKtosiTe and Jonah Bishop. My Windows 10 Pro still shows the useless lock screen (as if I'm using a touchscreen device, even though I'm using just a normal desktop PC) whenever I boot.

Comment: w32sh, see previous comments by people such as @oKtosiTe. How can we disable the lock screen even for boot (not just for wake)?

Comment: Ahhhh, I see from your comment on this other page that you're aware of this problem and don't know the solution: http://superuser.com/questions/1116351/disable-lock-screen-since-anniversary-update?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment1592475_1116351

Answer (score 0):

> ***EDIT:*** **Below method didn't really work well for me in the end (the "boot case" still shows the lock screen), but I'll leave it here for the record and in case someone has some idea how to improve it.**

An alternative method (not needing a Scheduled Task) seems to be:

1. *Start/Windows menu* → type `secpol.msc` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
2. In tree pane on the left, select *Software Restriction Policies* (node 6 of 9 total) → *Additional Rules*;

   - if you don't see it, select menu *Action* → *New Software Restriction Policies* to create it.
3. Right-click on the right pane (with "Name", "Security Level", etc) → *New Path Rule*, then:

   - In *Path*, paste: `C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.LockApp_cw5n1h2txyewy`
   - Make sure that *Security Level* is set to *Disallowed*;
   - Click *Ok*.

*Source: [ghacks.net](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/05/disable-windows-10-lock-screen/)*