# Disable Lock Screen (Since Anniversary Update)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

When I installed Windows 10, I created edited the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization` registry key by adding a `NoLockScreen` DWORD value and set it to 1. This had the effect of disabling the sliding panel on the lock screen, so that when my computer booted up or I locked my session, I would be presented with the password entry screen immediately (without having to press a key to slide the panel out of the way).

Unfortunately, the recent Anniversary Update seems to have undone this. I've tried deleting the value and re-adding it, but the lock screen is still present.

Is there some other way to remove the sliding-panel over the lock screen in Windows 10 which works for versions after the Anniversary Update?

I don't seem to have the local group policy editor in my version of Windows 10 Professional (possibly because I have the 32-bit operating system?).

Comment: There is a workaround posted here. But that won't still get rid of lock screen when you start the PC. (only works for lock) http://superuser.com/questions/1107480/how-do-i-kill-the-lockscreen-after-the-windows-10-anniversary-update