# How to Disable Windows 10 From Entering Lock Screen Automatically (Sleep Already Disabled)

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

I already disabled sleep on my windows laptop but from time to time it still enters lock screen. I like to know where to disable this feature.

p.s. I have tried to disable the sliding lock screen with no luck. It still requires me to enter the password. I don't want to disable the password but I want to prevent the system from locking the system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I kill the lockscreen after the Windows 10 anniversary update?](http://superuser.com/questions/1107480/how-do-i-kill-the-lockscreen-after-the-windows-10-anniversary-update)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1116351/disable-lock-screen-since-anniversary-update

Comment: No no, I have tried to disable the sliding lock screen with no luck. It still requires me to enter the password. I don't want to disable the password but I want to prevent the system from locking the system.

Comment: There are two screens in question.  The first is the lock screen, after you click on the screen, the second screen is where you logon.  Provide us a screenshot of the screen in question your trying to get rid of.

Comment: If you have the Anniversary Update and either Pro or Home, you cannot disable the lock screen. There is no registry hack like there was before the update.

Comment: Bill is 100% correct.  The duplicat question is the closest you can get.

Comment: Do you have a screensaver set (even to "none"), with "On resume, display logon screen" check marked?

Comment: The monitor turning off and the screenshot being set are two seperate group polciies so @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 you might be on to something.  Both can cause Windows to lock depending on the security settings.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it is off.

Comment: @BillOertell no I don't think there was an anniversary update installed.

Comment: @Ramhound the one that asks you to enter password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just based on the fact you want to keep the laptop on all the time, I assume you use remote desktop control to access the laptop, and likely from a mac. Once you do that, Windows will automatically lock the system if the laptop is inactive. This is really a bug and currently these is no fix.