# How to completely disable welcome screen on Windows 10 Anniversary?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there any possibility to completely disable the [welcome screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtFa1.jpg) on Windows 10 Anniversary?

I've tried: 
-`msconfig.exe` with no initialization GUI but no sucess.
-`gpedit.msc` --> Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Control Panel subfolders/Personalization folder to select it. Next, double-click the entry in the right pane of this window that says "Do not display the lock screen." Also without result.

`Fast startup`, `Sleep`, `Hibernate`, `Lock` in System settings are all enabled.
As far as I remember before anniversary the welcome screen was not there.

Comment: Enable the Group Policy for "Display Verbose messages" - you will not see the word Welcome anymore -you will instead receive real time information as to what your PC is doing. Most corporations enable verbose messages

Comment: @InterLinked Thanks a lot, doesn't answer my Q but it looks fine (also the custom background picture is there using this method).Meanwhile I've found [here](http://superuser.com/q/1107480/610149) the same question. It looks like there is no workaround at this moment in Win 10 Anniversary at least _at startup_.

Comment: What do you want to see instead of the Welcome screen? Right now it is difficult to tell what you want to accomplish, what your end goal is.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was trying to completely disable it at that time not to replace it with other image or something. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can look through this topic, maybe helps: [How to disable the Windows 8 swipe-away screen lock, without disabling the password?](https://superuser.com/questions/497736/how-to-disable-the-windows-8-lock-screen-without-disabling-the-password)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.superuser.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work the welcome screen is still there. Thanks anyway.