# Edit / Remove Windows 10 - Creators Welcome Screen

Tags: windows-10

There is a topic for this here that asks about removing the screen:
[How to completely disable welcome screen on Windows 10 Anniversary?](https://superuser.com/questions/1117871/how-to-completely-disable-welcome-screen-on-windows-10-anniversary)

However, that was for Windows 10-Anniversary and there was no resolution in that topic. Also, they wanted to completely remove the screen.

I am requesting information on removing the screen (in case there has been a solution since the initial topic or since the release of Creators), but am also open to removing assets on the screen. Removing the user set picture, name, and loading circle with the "Welcome" message. This way I can just set a custom background picture and that should be enough. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The other question never actually described what they wanted instead of the Welcome screen and as such, it is difficult to tell what their intended solution would look like. Could you explain what you'd like to see instead of the Welcome screen?

Comment: There haven’t been any changes with regards to the welcome screen

Comment: Would probably like to see a black or some other colored screen. Removing the assets and just having the background still there works though. There are methods of changing the background so I could just make picture the same as the desktop background so it essentially looks like a smooth transition from boot to bringing up the environment.