# How to avoid getting the "Username Welcome" message during Win10Pro (1903) login?

Tags: windows-10-v1903

*(Note: this question is about version 1903 of Windows 10 (May 2019), and is not a duplicate of the question about version 1607, also known as "Windows Anniversary" (December 2015), none of the answers to which offer a solution to the current question.)*

I recently installed Windows 10 Pro (version 1903) on a new laptop. After the machine is powered on I would like the Windows login to occur without any further user input. I have achieved this, in that there is only one user (let's call him Ruffle), who has administrator privileges, and no password is required for him to log in. However, before I get my Windows desktop I am getting a welcome message on the screen which says "Welcome Ruffle". How can I get rid of this, so that there is no message on the screen and in particular there is no reference to any username, or to a generic "other user", before I get the Windows desktop?

If it is relevant (I doubt it is), I am using Open Shell, the current incarnation of Classic Shell.

Comment: Turn off your display, or don't use Windows 10. Seriously though, this is not something you can change. The welcome screen will always be shown. If your pc is fast (with SSD and plenty of RAM) it may be too fast to see. Otherwise, you could alter the displayname and remove the ruffle alltogether.

Comment: I agree and it is also entirely insecure to have no password. Set up a password and it will make more sense to you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to completely disable welcome screen on Windows 10 Anniversary?](https://superuser.com/questions/1117871/how-to-completely-disable-welcome-screen-on-windows-10-anniversary)

Comment: Why not just change the user name to "generic"

Comment: @TomYan - If spaces were allowed I might use "Hello and". Perhaps I should call myself "Warm" :-)

Comment: @John - I already know what the login password function does, and also why I don't want to use it. Activating it wouldn't give me any greater understanding of it than I have already.