# Remove Lock Screen from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, regedit, lock-screen

How do you remove the lock screen from windows 10? The one with the random image which you have to [enter] away before going to the login input?

I had it removed until 2 weeks ago, but some windows update has undone that setting.

The regedit setting for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization[NoLockScreen=1]` is not working anymore. Not sure why.

P.S.: I'm running Windows 10 Home

Comment: i concur. That does seem like a possible culprit

Answer (score 2):

The possibility of hiding the lock screen at boot was removed in the Windows 10 anniversary update.
There are ways of hiding it when locking the computer, as stated in the duplicate
[How do I kill the lockscreen after the Windows 10 anniversary update?](https://superuser.com/questions/1107480/how-do-i-kill-the-lockscreen-after-the-windows-10-anniversary-update)
, but so far I've seen no way disabling the lock screen at boot.

Well there is one way. Editing the LogonController.dll file. 
Not sure it's a very wise thing to do, but it works.

Apparently "0xBF50 48 89 5C 24 08 -> C3 90 90 90 90" is the key value here.

If you are feeling lucky, there is a modified 64-bit version, 10.0.14393.0 dll file at:

*Link removed*

**Tested again February 2017, with the modified dll and windows won't boot at all, removing the link**