# Windows 10 login screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, login-screen

Windows 10 lock screen requires that I press 'enter' or some other key before I can enter my password. If, as soon as I turn on the computer, I start typing my password the first character activates the password box rather than being the first character.

So... My question is: does anyone know how I can change this behavior? I want to just be able to type my password in, without having to press a key before doing so.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe your attempting to disable the lock screen, this screen as of Windows 10 Version 1607, cannot be disabled.  You can only disable this screen with a group policy if your running Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid entering the password, or keep the password and eliminate one keystroke?

Comment: @fixer1234 The latter. I would like my computer to continue to have a password, I would also like to be able to start typing the password when I want to log on. Rather than press space or enter, wait for the screen to load, then to enter the password.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I posted a fix on it when it was asked on this question: http://superuser.com/questions/1137151/remove-lock-screen-from-windows-10/1137208#1137208 And that worked for me. However, after a while and a few updates, it's back to normal again. Haven't tried to apply the fix again. Might work, but maybe not anymore. Very annoying "feature".