# How Can Windows 10 When Locking Go to Lock Screen?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, lock-screen

Is there a way to get a PC running Windows 10 Pro to go to the lock screen when locking instead of the login screen?

[image: Lock Screen and Login Screen Picture]

---

**Scenario:**

- Three tested computers go to lock screen on boot.
- Locking a PC running Windows 10 Home (with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, for example) makes it go to the lock screen
- Locking two PCs running Windows 10 Pro makes them go to the login screen.

How can I make it so that the two Windows 10 Pro computers go to the lock screen when locking, and not just at boot?

> Windows 10 Pro Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.799)

---

**Settings and Research...**

- Settings > Accounts > Sign-In Options

  - "If you've been away, when should Windows require you to sign in again?"
  - set to "Never"
  - Then tried elevated CMD commands to reset Group Policy

  `RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicyUsers"`
  `RD /S /Q "%WinDir%\System32\GroupPolicy"`
  `gpupdate /force`

  - And looked at Windows Key + R, rsop.msc
  - Can't see much yet.
  - Local Group Polices under Personalization all `Not Configured`.
    [image: Local Group Polices]
  - `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System` is Empty
  - Screensaver turned off. `On resume, display logon screen` un-ticked.
    [image: Screensaver Settings Windows 10]
  - The known registry key is already set to 1 as posts would describe:

> ```
> reg.exe add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData /t REG_DWORD /v AllowLockScreen /d 1 /f
> ```

[Source 1](https://superuser.com/a/1110068/900431), [Source 2](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/disable-lock-screen-anniversary-update-windows-10/)

- Can also be turned off completely also by adding the following key:

> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization
> ```
>
> New Dword: `NoLockScreen`, Set to `1`

Also noticed these key locations; to no avail:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager *
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lock Screen *
HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop LockScreenAutoLockActive
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\DeviceLock * sub folders
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\WindowsLogon * sub folders
```

*Update: 13/6/2019: Now believe it is likely caused by fast user logon or user switching.*

***Tried Disabling Fast User Switching in Windows 10***

> ```
>   :: Created by: Shawn Brink
>   :: Created on: October 13th 2017
> :: Tutorial: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95383-enable-disable-fast-user-switching-windows-10-a.html
>
>
> powershell -windowstyle hidden -command "Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/s,/c,REG ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /V
> HideFastUserSwitching /T REG_DWORD /D 00000001 /F & REG Delete
> HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /V
> HideFastUserSwitching /F & taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & start
> explorer.exe' -Verb runAs"
> ```

[Source](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/95383-enable-disable-fast-user-switching-windows-10-a.html)

*All it did was remove the users for fast login from the menu, so reverted.*

Comment: What do you define as the lock screen vs logon screen?

Comment: Is your problem the "Force a specific default lock screen and logon image" GPO which doesn't work correctly since 1803?

Comment: Your question states that Windows 10 PCs lock to both the login screen and the lock screen. You need to make it clearer which version of Windows 10 you want to change here.

Comment: Have you checked the screen-saver on these computers?

Comment: Do you have any sub-keys or values in the registry in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System`? Do you have a `Personalization` key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows` and what does it contain?

Comment: In Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`), are there any configured policies in *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization*?

Comment: In *Settings > Accounts > Sign-In Options*, on the top, is "If you've been away, when should Windows require you to sign in again?"  set to "Never"?

Comment: I'm all out of ideas. My last idea is to compare two computers where this happens and not, if they are reasonably similar. Some tools I found are a free [Powershell Tool](http://www.systanddeploy.com/2015/12/powershell-tool-compare-two-computer.html) and the free+commercial [ENVy Computer Compare](https://envy-computer-compare.soft112.com/) with [writeup](https://www.ghacks.net/2010/02/01/computer-system-environment-comparison-software/).

Comment: Great effort @harrymc , I will follow up on suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run Ultimate Windows Tweaker 4.5
   [image]
2. `Customization` --> `Universal UI`
3. Untick `Enable User Switching So That User List Appears On Logon`
4. Apply Teaks
5. `Windows + L` now shows Lock Screen image.

[image: Lock Screen Image now showing]

*Note: Have not found the corresponding registry tweak, windows setting or group policy setting yet that works on these machine. But at least it is resolved!*

> **Ultimate Windows Tweaker 4.5**
>
> The most popular tweaking software, Ultimate Windows Tweaker 4 for
>   Windows 10 adds several new tweaks for the new operating system. Those
>   of you who have upgraded to Windows 10, would definitely want to use
>   it to judiciously tweak your Windows 10 and personalize your computing
>   experience. With judicious tweaking, it can make your system faster,
>   more stable, personal and more secure with just a few mouse clicks.
>
> Ultimate Windows Tweaker is like a TweakUI for Windows 10. While you
>   may be able to access all these via the Windows 10 Settings app, the
>   Registry Editor or the Group Policy Editor, Ultimate Windows Tweaker
>   makes things easier for you by offering all useful tweaks from its
>   single UI.
>
> [Website](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/ultimate-windows-tweaker-4-windows-10) and [Direct Download](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/your-download-of-uwt4-will-start-in-5-seconds)