# How to make Windows 10 startup with PIN screen?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

When I turn on my Windows 10, it shows a beautiful background picture, then I have to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then it will show the PIN Textbox.

It it there a way to avoid having to type <kbd>Enter</kbd> every time I want to login?

Comment: If you have a pin set, then that should be the default authorization used, you should simply be able to start typing your pin.

Comment: If I start typing, the first key I press brings up the PIN Textbox, so it's ignored.

Comment: Do you have multiple users by chance?  My 1903 system, when I present with the screen you describe, I simply click with my mouse and start typing.  Anyways, if I am not mistaken, it's called the lock screen.  So if you disable it, you should be present with the screen, so you can log into the last logged into account with a pin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I kill the lockscreen after the Windows 10 anniversary update?](https://superuser.com/questions/1107480/how-do-i-kill-the-lockscreen-after-the-windows-10-anniversary-update)

Comment: I just have 1 user, and I don't click, I hit Enter. I am kinda "lazy", I like optimized systems, so going for my mouse, just for a click, then coming back to the keyboard is wasteful, so I hit Enter and type, as I am right there at the keyboard anyway. Even more optimized is if I don't have to type Enter at all :)

Comment: I don't want to disable the Lock Screen, I just want the PIN Textbox to be shown by default

Comment: If you want to just be able to log in without clicking first, then yes, you want to disable the lock screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are a couple of ways to set this. Although I haven't got a PIN set up, I assume this should work for you.

If your edition of Windows 10 is Pro or Enterprise then you have access to the Group Policy Editor. Run `gpedit.msc`, go into Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization. In the right panel, find "Do not display lock screen" and Set to Enabled. This should take effect as soon as you press OK. For me, I was able to lock my machine and jump straight to the password prompt.

[image: Group Policy Editor]

If you are on any other edition, you can do the same thing by changing the registry. The path you need to change (or create if it doesn't exist) is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization` and once there, make/set the `DWORD` called `NoLockScreen` with value `1`.

[image: Registry editor]

The source for this answer was found in [this article](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-the-windows-10-lock-screen/), and its comments. It gives a full break-down on how to find or make the relevant registry key.

Comment: The wording on "do not display the lock screen" makes me believe it won't have a password at all, ok, I will give it a try.

Comment: Yes, the wording is strange. I definitely still have a password prompt on my lock screen, just without the pre-lock screen.

Comment: It works.... But is it possible to have the same thing without the blur effect on the background? When my laptop fails to recognize my face it shows the PIN without any blur, I wanted the same at my desktop

Comment: That's probably something built into Windows. You'd have to get some 3rd-party software to change it.