# In Windows 11, how do I boot directly into the login screen?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, login-screen, lock-screen

In Windows 7, booting up took you directly to the Login Screen where you could immediately start typing your password. By contrast, Windows 10 and 11 have an intermediate Lock Screen that require you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before you can actually go to the Login Screen to start typing your password.

**How do I bypass the Lock Screen and go straight to the Login Screen on Windows 11?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I kill the lockscreen after the Windows 10 anniversary update?](https://superuser.com/questions/1107480/how-do-i-kill-the-lockscreen-after-the-windows-10-anniversary-update).  I verified that the duplicate's answer was a 1:1 to the answer that was submitted to this question before I raised the duplicate flag.  *If you disagree with this duplicate flag, please go through the proper channels, instead of replying with a comment.*

Comment: Had this exact same question, and yes, that half-unresponsive intermediate lock screen on boot was driving me insane. Thank you for asking this!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Lock Screen can be disabled in one of two ways: by editing the Registry directly, or by using the Group Policy Editor.

---

## Using the Registry

Editing the Registry is always risky, and you should first create a System Restore point before going any further. You can either edit the Registry manually, or run the `.reg` file I've provided below, which is safer and more reliable.

#### Edit the Registry manually

1. Open the Registry Editor by searching for it in the search bar
2. Navigate to the following key by pasting it into the Registry Editor's search and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows
   ```
3. Within that key, look for a key called `Personalization`, or create it if it doesn't exist
4. Right-click on the Personalization key, select `New > DWORD (32-Bit Value)`, and name the value NoLockScreen
5. Double-click on the newly-created value and change its value to 1

#### Run the Registry file

1. Create a new plain text file and copy and paste the following into it:

   ```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization]
    "NoLockScreen"=dword:00000001
   ```
2. Rename the file so that it ends with a `.reg` extension
3. Double-click on the file to run it, and click Yes to confirm

The next time you restart, you will boot directly into the login screen.

---

## Using the Group Policy Editor (Professional and Enterprise only)

The Group Policy Editor tool is only available in the Professional and Enterprise editions of Windows 10 and 11, and is typically only used in network environments. It makes its changes by adding the same keys to the Registry that I did above, and should best be seen as a graphical interface for system and network administrators to more manageably apply registry changes across an entire network.

Therefore, if you're only making the change to a single PC, you shouldn't need to use the GPE  unless you're having trouble editing the Registry directly.

#### Change the policy in the Group Policy Editor

1. Open the Group Policy Editor by searching for `Edit group policy` in the search bar
2. In the sidebar, select `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Control Panel > Personalization`
3. Double-click on the `Do not display the lock screen` policy and set it to `Enabled`
4. Click `Apply`

The next time you restart, you'll boot directly into the login screen.

Comment: Will this allow the lock screen timeout to lock the workstation (going to the login screen / password input) or will it disable that?

Comment: I can say that the "Using the Registry section" above also worked for Windows 11 Pro (21H2 build 22000.348)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can confirm it still works with Windows 11 Home, 22H2.